# How to autowire Service using Symfony DI with container->get(...)

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm writing a small lib (named FileToObject) and I'd like to use the Symfony dependency injection component in this lib, without using the Symfony framework itself. So in my lib I have an entrypoint class, where I read my service configuration, instanciate my DI container and try to get a service (named `Denormalizer`):

```php
<?php

namespace FileToObject;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

class Reader
{
    protected ContainerBuilder $container;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // instanciating the DI container
        $this->container = new ContainerBuilder();
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($this->container, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
        // load service configuration
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }

    // ...

    public function dataToObject(array $data, string $rootClassPath): object
    {
        // trying to get the service
        $denormalizer = $this->container->get(Denormalizer::class);
        // ...
    }
}
```

The service configuration is located together with the rest of the lib code in the same directory and looks like this:

```yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        public: true

    FileToObject\:
        resource: './*'
```

So from my understanding, every class in my code should be usable as a public service, d.i. usable with `$containter->get(...)` and should be autowired.

This does however not hold for my `Denormalizer`-Service, which has the following Signature (ReflectionCache is just another class in my lib):

```php
class Denormalizer
{
    public function __construct(protected ReflectionCache $reflections) {
    }
    // ...
}
```

When trying to execute the code, I get the following Error:

```
Too few arguments to function FileToObject\Denormalizer::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

So the Denormalizer-Service is found, but not autowired. **How can I get the container to autowire this Service, if possible?**

Edit:
Forgot to mention, that the symfony components are connected to symfony v6.3.

Comment: I think the denormalizer has no service definition or the service container cannot resolve the parameter in the constructor. You can debug the services container: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/debug.html

Comment: Thanks for your tip! The Denormalizer Service certainly is registered, otherwise the error would state, that no Denormalizer-Service was found. Or did you mean something else? So agree with you, that the container cannot resove the parameter in the constructor, the question is why? Also I cannot use any symfony commands for debugging, since I do not use the symfony framework.

Comment: That is right, you are right. If the service was not registered, there would be a different error message.

Answer (score 1):

I have built your case and can reproduce the error message. At the moment, I cannot explain why there is no autowire with ReflectionCache. Actually, it should work that way. I am not sure if it is related to this because DependencyInjection is used as a standalone.

A possible solution would be:

```yaml
services:

  # ...

  denormalizer_service:
    class: FileToObject\Denormalizer
    arguments:
      - '@FileToObject\ReflectionCache'
```

```php
$this->container->get('denormalizer_service');
```

Comment: Thanks for testing, at least I can now be sure not to have overlooked something substancial. But I really want to have autowiring with the symfony DI container working. This lib is only a small one and configuring DI may be an option, but I plan for more.

Comment: Until your question, I thought I understood Symfony DI :-). I have just looked at Symfony projects and am currently wondering why it does not work.  Soon there will be another Symfony User Group and I will take your case with me and ask other developers. But maybe someone will answer here with the right solution.

Comment: My guess is, that it was never really meant to work with a standalone lib. Also the Doc states, that it is bad practice to use autowiring in bundles (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#public-and-reusable-bundles), although I do not fully agree to their reasoning, as long as there are certain rules about what to autowire inside a package. Anyways, for now I use PHP-DI, but I will certainly miss some of the features of the symfony di.

Comment: You could try asking on the Symfony discussion board but I'm pretty sure you need to wire up one or more extensions to get the autowire functionality. This [article](https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/experiment-how-i-replaced-symfony-di-with-laravel-container-in-ecs) might help.

Comment: @LordBo https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for the link. The Laravel service container might also be an option and I will definetly check it out. But I'd like to have tagged iterable autowiring and I don't know, if Laravel can do that (the autowire part).

Comment: @LordBo The same author has some additional articles in which they seem determined to force the Laravel container to act like the Symfony one.  To a certain extent they don't seem to realize that the additional Symfony functionality is what makes it a bit more difficult to configure.  There is also a few other questions on this topic.  Seems like at least one of them used autowire.